# How to identify a broadcasted message?

Tags: python

Sometimes I have to send a message to a specific IP and sometimes I have to broadcast the message to all the IP's in my network. At the other end I have to distinguish between a broadcast and a normal one, but `recvfrom()` just returns the address the message came from;
there is no difference between them. Can anyone help me distinguish them?

UDP is the protocol.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it's possible with Python's `socket` module. UDP is a very minimalistic protocol, and the only way to distinguish between a broadcast and a non-broadcast UDP packet is by looking at the destination address. However, you cannot inspect that part of the packet with the BSD socket API (if I remember it correctly), and the `socket` module exposes the BSD socket API only. Your best bet would probably be to use the first byte of the message to denote whether it is a broadcast or a unicast message.